# auto ranging y axis in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly

I want to plot a graph in plotly. while set the range to zoom with rangelider, the y axis is fixed and make data in flat. I found a page that one expert guy did it, but I can not do it

Is there any one that can make it happen

https://community.plotly.com/t/y-axis-autoscaling-with-x-range-sliders/10245/11

at this page the second graph is a animation gif this is what exactly I have to do

Comment: You mentioned that you cannot do it. Can you show us what you have tried and what error your are getting or what is going wrong so we can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same technique but using **dash** to capture event and trigger **callback**. Additional reference: [graph slider as input](https://community.plotly.com/t/callback-on-graph-slider-change-which-property-to-use-as-input/33979/2)

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate some data and a figure...
s = 500
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("1-jan-2020", periods=s), "val": np.random.uniform(0, 1, s)})
df = df.assign(val=df["val"] * (df["date"] - df["date"].min()).dt.days ** 3)

fig = px.line(df, x="date", y="val")
fig = fig.update_layout(xaxis={"rangeslider": {"visible": True}, "range":[df["date"].quantile(.75), df["date"].max()]})

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='dashFig', figure=fig),
], style={"font-family": "Arial", "font-size":"0.9em"})

# get callback from rangeslider and update ranges on x & y axis
@app.callback(Output('dashFig', 'figure'),
            [Input('dashFig', 'relayoutData')])
def rangesliderchg(relayoutData):
    if relayoutData and "xaxis.range" in relayoutData.keys():
        s = df.loc[df["date"].between(relayoutData['xaxis.range'][0], relayoutData['xaxis.range'][1]), "val"]
        fig["layout"]["yaxis"]["range"] = [s.min(), s.max()]
        fig["layout"]["xaxis"]["range"] = relayoutData['xaxis.range']
    return fig

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode='inline')
```